# save data to new worksheet, in existing workbook using python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl

created a new *dataframe* named ***df3*** and saved to excel workbook named *masterdata.xlsx*, later created another *dataframe named table* when I try to write that dataframe to sheet2 of masterdata.xlsx, it overrighted the first created dataframe.

masterdata.xlsx have two sheets, sheet1 and sheet2. sheet1 have some data. ***how to save newly created dataframe table to sheet2 without losing sheet1 using python.***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create pandas excel writer and then save on different sheets like this:

```
df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet2')
```